# How can I unescape HTML escape character from JSP to Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, html-escape-characters, html-escape

I am applying `fn:escapeXml` to a input value (say `>`) in JSP to do html escape. When I submit the form, I do need to send the parameter to the controller. In my controller, the request parameter comes as `&gt` and not `&gt;`. Because of this, I could not unescape in the controller to get the original value. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: What is backticks.. could u please help me.

Comment: I've edited your code. Take a look [at it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13137781/revisions) for how I've done it. And see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans

Comment: Many thanks Tichodroma. I am yet to get what is backticks :(.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent

Comment: If you take a look at the [source code of JstlFunction.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/2.0.x/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/tag/jstl/fn/JstlFunction.java) which contains `fn:escapeXml` you will see this: `case '>' : app = "&gt;"; break;` Are you sure, you only get `&gt` *without* the `;`?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.. Tichodroma. The parameter is encoded in the URL and %2526gt%253B is the value. It gives me &gt in the request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18784/discussion-between-tichodroma-and-sridhar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons Lang - String Escape Utils

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Use one of the unescape methods.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, create a custom method, and replace all string occurrences of &gt with > and do similar operation for other html characters.

Comment: Hi Yashpal.. many thanks for the response. There are many html escape characters. It is difficult to manage using a custom method right.

Comment: Yes right, if you don't have any restriction on special characters in your input.